# Load img in window.opener from child window using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, load, refresh

Im trying to set image in window.opener from open window like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var linkID =$(this).attr("id");         
        var imgSrcVal = $('img', this).attr("src");

        window.opener.document.getElementById("id_1").src=imgSrcVal;
     });
});
```

in the parent window i have img tag that looks like this :

```
<tr>
    <td style="height:250px;">
        <img src=""   width="110" height="250px" id="id_1"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

can it be set and shown without refresh ? and if not how can i do it in ajax way ?

Comment: What happens when you use the code that you have posted? Also, is the origin for both window's content same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the domain of the opener and the current window are same ([Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). If that is true the paths for the opener and current widnow may not be same. Try making the image Url absolute...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var linkID =$(this).attr("id");         
        var imgSrcVal = $('img', this).attr("src");

        if (location.href.indexOf("/") != 0) {
            var base = location.href.replace(/(.+)(\/)(.*)/, "$1");
            imgSrcVal = base + "/" + imgSrcVal;
        }

        window.opener.document.getElementById("id_1").src = imgSrcVal;
     });
});
```